# Who was R Abba Shaul's mother, Imma Miriam?

Tags: maseches-kesubos, amoroim

Asking about the mother of אַבָּא שָׁאוּל בֶּן אִימָּא מִרְיָם, who is mentioned in Kesuvos 87a and other places in the gemara.

Is there any information about "Imma Miriam": who she was, why her son is referenced this way instead of "ben FathersName"?

Comment: The title Abba is an honorific as is the title Imma. It would seem that his father wasn’t as honorable as his mother. (Berachos 16B)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yad Eliyahu Nashim, p. 50 says:

אבא שאול בן אימא מרים עיין בהגהות הנ"ר יעב"ץ שכ' שהוא לשון מרות וחשיבות כמ"ש בברכות טז ב קורין אותן אבא פלוני אמא פלונית ומצינו עוד כעין זה שם לאשה בשבת קטן ג ובנדרים כ א וב"מ נט ב אימא שלום אשתו של ר"א ואחותו של ר"ג ונ"ל ששם זה נלקח מלשון הכתוב בשופטים ה' עד שקמתי דבורה שקמתי אם בישראל כי לולא זאת ששמה נודע בשערים ומפורסמת יותר מבעלה היו קורין אותו על שם אביו ולכן הוסיפו תיבת אימא ולא אמרו בן מרים משום שאז היי נראה כרב מרי בר רחל המובא כ"פ בש"ס כמו בשבת קנד ב וביבמות מה ב וב"מ עג ב וזהו משום שאביו הי' גר קראוהו על שם אמו אבל כאן קראוה אימא מרים ע"ש שהיא היתה מפורסמת בשמה עוסקת בצרכי הרבים כמו אם בישראל הנאמר בדבורה הנביאה ולא כההיא שאמרו בנדה ט ב כל שקורין לה אמא ואינה בושה מחמת זקנה ע"ש ליה

In short, the title "אימא" is an honorific and due to the piety of אימא מרים and her laboring on behalf of the needs of the community she was of greater renown than his father. Furthermore, once he was going to be known by his mother it would have been improper to simply leave it at בן מרים as this might imply something incorrect regarding his paternal parentage (e.g. son of a convert).